# How do I fix this unknown TypeError when rendering my page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I am building this react app and when I serve it on my local server i get this error in my console:
Uncaught TypeError:

```
react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default(...).render is not a function
    at ./src/index.js (index.js:6:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at startup:7:1
    at startup:7:1
```

my index.js file has the following code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react";
import App from "./App";


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

and the code for my app.js file:

```
function App() {
    return <h1>Hello from the app component</h1>
}

export default App
```

I do not understand why I am getting this error. Can someone please help me figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

The default export of the `'react'` module is React. To get ReactDOM, you need to import from [react-dom](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html).

```
import ReactDOM from "react";
```

should change to

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

You should also consider [if you're using React 18](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-client.html), in which case you should use `.createRoot` instead.

```
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector('#root')).render(<App />);
```